# Given a XML file, I am writing Bash to parse it, but need to create a header and break up a date string?

Tags: xml, bash, grep, sh

Given a XML file, I am writing Bash to parse it, but need help with header and breaking strings?  This is what I have so far:

```
<dbg><h><d t="2013/08/11 (Aug) (Sun) 00:56:23.491" m="CANLogging" f="../../../ApplCtrl/CANMessageLoger.cpp" l="120" fnc="void CANMessageLoger::WriteToLog(uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint8_t, uint8_t*)" lvl="DBG_EVENT" thrd=""/></h><b> d2    ff    f7   0c 10 27 ff ff ff ff ff </b></dbg>
```

---

```
grep CANLogging $1 |  awk '{printf("%s %s",$2,$5); i=18; while(i<NF) { printf("  %s", $i); ++i} printf("\n");}'  | awk -F "\"" '{print $2 " " $3}' > CAN
```

---

There are about a couple 100,000 lines of the following produced from grep:

```
2013/08/11 00:56:23.491   d2  ff  f7  0c  10  27  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
```

---

---

---

But I need to add a header to the output file:

```
Date     Time        source Format Specific data
```

---

And for the date string to be parsed and altered a bit to be:

```
13.08.11 00:56:23.491   d2  ff  f7  0c  10  27  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff
```

using svante, I get:

```
grep CANLogging $1 |  awk '{printf("%s %s",$2,$5); i=18; while(i<NF) { printf("  %s", $i); ++i} printf("\n");}'  | awk -F "\"" 'BEGIN{print "Date     Time        source Format Specific data"}{print $2 " " $3}' | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\//\2.\3./' > CAN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Alter your last awk to include the header and pipe to sed for a simple date format change :

```
... | awk -F "\"" 'BEGIN{print "Date     Time        source Format Specific data"}{print $2 " " $3}' | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\//\2.\3./' > CAN
```

The `awk` BEGIN rule is executed, once, before the first input record has been read

The `sed` command matches and replaces the first date numeric and separator characters for each line

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work (first line adds header to new file, second line parses the date). If more parsing is necessary, take a look at sed.

```
echo "Date     Time        source Format Specific data" > new.file
sed 's/2013\//13./g' old.file | sed 's/\//./g' >> new.file
```